# export als recommendation model to a file

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to Apache Spark. I ran the sample ALS algorithm code present in the examples folder. I gave a csv file as an input. When I use *model.save(path)* to save the model, it is stored in *gz.parquet* file.

[When I tried to open this file, I get these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxKAe.png)

Now I want to store the recommendation model generated in a text or csv file for using it outside Spark.

I tried the following function to store the model generated in a file but it was useless:

```
model.saveAsTextFile("path")
```

Please suggest me a way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out `saveAsTextFile()` only works on the slaves.Use `collect()` to collect the data from the slaves so it can be saved locally on the master. Solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197852/how-to-store-the-text-file-on-the-master)

Answer (score 1):

Lest say you have trained your model with something like this:

```
val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)
```

All that you have to do is:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating    
// Save
model.save(sc, "yourpath/yourmodel")
// Load Model
val sameModel = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "yourpath/yourmodel")
```

Comment: The above snippet is already added in the code. I want to save the recommendation model in a text file. I want to use this recommendation text  file in an another application (outside Spark).

Comment: The above code snippet saves the model in a folders containing gz.parquet files.

Comment: You can iterate over all your training data extracting a prediction for each point of your data and write it in a text file. Then you will need a method to load that predictions in your target model (scikit or whatever).

Comment: After performing prediction on the training data, when i try to store the data in text file, the text file only contains the path of the directory. The model produced after prediction is in the RDD format. I want to store this RDD in textual format in a text file

Comment: If the problem is to write the RDD into a TextFile, you can do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666361/process-spark-streaming-rdd-and-store-to-single-hdfs-file/31669187#31669187