# Spark saveAsTextFile overwrites file after each batch

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am currently trying to use Spark streaming to get input from a Kafka topic and hence save that input in a Json file. I got so far, that I can save my InputDStream as a textFile, but the Problem is, after each batch-process the File gets overwritten, and it seems like I cannot do anything about this.

Is there a method or config option at all to change this?
I tried `spark.files.overwrite ,false`
but it did not work.

My Code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("local-test").setMaster("local[*]")
            .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
            .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
            .set("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
            .set("spark.rdd.compress", "true").set("spark.executor.instances","4").set("spark.executor.memory","6G")
            .set("spark.executor.cores","6")
            .set("spark.cores.max","8")
            .set("spark.driver.memory","2g")
            .set("spark.files.overwrite","false");





    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(4));



    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "xxxxx");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "ID2");

    List<String> topics = Arrays.asList("LEGO_MAX");


    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));



    JavaDStream<String> first = stream.map(record -> (record.value()).toString());
    first.foreachRDD(rdd -> rdd.saveAsTextFile("C:\\Users\\A675866\\Hallo.txt"));


    ssc.start();

    try {
        ssc.awaitTermination();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to cut connection -> Throwing Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you expect the data to be appended?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want

Comment: have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017366/how-can-i-make-spark1-6-saveastextfile-to-append-existing-file

RDDs saveAsTextFile doesn't support append, but a workaround is suggested.
Also, if you're will map your RDD to a spark sql dataset, you could use append.