# How to append content of Dstream or RDD to an existing output file - Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working on simple SparkStreaming wordcount example to count the number of words in text data received from a data server listening on a TCP socket. 
I would like to save the content of every Dstream that are not empty to an existing text file. Currently, I am using Spark Shell. This is my code

I have tried this code, and it works but it overwrites the current file:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

lines.foreachRDD{ rdd => if (!rdd.isEmpty) 
//.% to check if the Dstream is empty or not  
{
rdd.saveAsTextFile("/stream_test/testLine.txt")
}
}

ssc.start()
```

I appreciate your valuable help

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39917679/647053)

Comment: Thanks, I am not using the HDFS, and I am using spark-shell which is not compatible with what you suggested